# moving label to centre of cell

Tags: iphone

i have created my label using this

```
UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
```

i want to move my label to centre of the cell...
can any one answer it....
thank you for valuable answers...

Answer (score 1):

The cell's center point is in the cell.superview's coordinates, just convert that point to the cell's coordinates and set the label's center there:

```
label1.center = [cell.superview convertPoint:cell.center toView:cell];
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the labels frame to the appropriate offset :

```
x=cell.frame.width/2-label1.frame.width/2;

y=cell.frame.height/2-label1.frame.height/2;

label1.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,cell.frame.width,cell.frame.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code adds a label to the center of a collection view cell.

```
// self is the current cell.
UILabel *pointLabel =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
pointLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
pointLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
pointLabel.text = @"+300";
[self addSubview:pointLabel];
```

Hope this helps.